# vue.js textbox disappears with v-model keyword

Tags: javascript, vue.js

One day old vue.js programmer here. No experience with Javascript either. First time asking question on this forum.

Modifying someone else's code. Whenever I add v-model keyword, the control stops displaying.

## Javscript

```
var layoutHeader = Vue.extend({
    template: '#layout-header-tpl',
    props: ['userinfo']
});
```

## Html

1. This works, textbox is displayed (there is no v-model keyword)

```html
    <template id="layout-header-tpl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </template>
```

2) This does not work, textbox disappeares (added v-model keyword)

```html
<template id="layout-header-tpl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" v-model="something1234">
</template>
```

3) This does not work, textbox disappeares (removed id from template)

```html
<template>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" v-model="something1234">
</template>
```

4) This works, textbox is displayed (commented out the template)

```html
<!--<template>-->
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" v-model="something1234">
<!--</template>-->
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use [Vue devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to see what is going wrong? You may be able to find a solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are trying to reuse / modify someone else's code.  I believe you are trying to do some kind of "inheritance" by using `Vue.extend`.

If so, please note that inheritance is **not recommended**. For details, here is the link to discussion topic: https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/354

That discussion was around Vue 1.0 version, but I believe it is still relevant for Vue 2.0.

As mentioned in that page, if you are working in a team and sharing code / components, then you may use `mixins` instead. You will find more details in the docs: http://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html

Comment: Sorry, 'reuse' was not the correct word. I basically copied the project and started working on it :) I will also check these links. Thanks for that.